# Every user is a new thread JSF - JBOSS and creates new connection in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, jsf, mongo-java

I'm trying to work with mongoDB. I created in JSF application scoped bean (with CDI).

```
@Named("appMongo")
@ApplicationScoped
public class MongoApplicationScope implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private DB db = null;
private MongoClient mongoClient = null;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
try {
    mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    db = mongoClient.getDB("mydb");
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public DB getDb() {
return db;
}

public DBCollection getCollectionInDatabase(String collection) {
    DBCollection coll;
    coll = db.getCollection(collection);
    return coll;
}

public MongoClient getMongoClient() {
    return mongoClient;
}
}
```

Then I create request scoped bean which is using prevoius bean.

```
@Named("mongoBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MongoBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Inject MongoApplicationScope mongoAccess;
public void pringNumber() {
System.out.println(mongoAccess.getCollectionInDatabase("mydb").getCount());

}
}
```

On xhtml page I have commandButton with actionListener which calls "printNumber" method.
In result each user which connect to jboss server and click on the button open new connection to mongo. I don't want that kind situation. I would like to achive situation where I have only 1 connection bettwen server and db, and each user reuse that connection.

Answer (score 1):

The MongoDB driver maintains an own connection pool. Connections can't and shouldn't be shared between request (think of server side cursors which would be shared, too). However, connections will be reused after they were handed back to the pool. Until they are used again, they will be kept alive for a certain period of time, since a new connection to the database isn't cheap to acquire. The TCP three way handshake takes quite some time, so keeping connections open does make sense. In fact, in with RDBMS you have to walk a mile to achieve this desired behaviour, for example with C3p0 or DBCP.

For your reference: your connection pool size (and thus the number of your potentially open connections to your database server) should be at least the number of executor threads of your servlet engine so that nobody has to wait for an other request to finish before even the database connection is available (not to mention the queried data). With a full blown application server, I'd add another 20-50 connections, depending on the configuration. This is the way to go, wether you are using MongoDB or not. Depending on your deployment, these are some 200-550 connections.

The good side:

1. MongoDB connections are pretty lightweight in terms of RAM. On the client side, we are talking of a few KB per idle connection, on the server side 1MB is allocated.
2. You can configure the driver on how many connections to use. Be warned that fiddling with the number of connections may have *severe* consequences in terms of performance under load. Please see [the API docs of `MongoClientOptions.Builder`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.Builder.html) for details.
3. The default values of the driver actually are rather conservative in terms of resource usage. For example, the maximum number of connections per host defaults is set to 100, which for any serious application is a bit low.

To make a long story short: Unless experiencing problems, never touch a running system.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to replace

```java
@Inject MongoApplicationScope mongoAccess;
```

with

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{appMongo}")
private MongoApplicationScope mongoAccess;
```

and add setter/getter for `mongoAccess`.

Comment: OP is using CDI `@Named`, not JSF `@ManagedBean`.